# Trying to change the color of table if the given time is equal or higher than current time

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form where you can type in a given time for example 12:30.

Default the table color is blue but i want it to change color if the current real time is 12:30 or above (example: 12:40).

I need to fetch the given time from the database (already managed that) but the next part is to get the current time and if its equal or higher than the input time change color of the whole table

(Inntid is the value where you type in your own time)

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Båt ut</th>
        <th>Båt inn</th>
        <th>Båtnr</th>
        <th>Fornavn</th>
        <th>Etternavn</th>
        <th>Tid</th>
        <th>Kr</th>
    </tr>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    color: blue;
outline-style: solid;
width: 100%;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 25px;
text-align:left;

}

  th {
color: red;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 25px;
text-align:left;
  }
```

PHP:

```
$sok = @$_POST['searchh'];
$sql = "SELECT utleid, inntid, baatnr, fornavn, etternavn, tid, kr FROM     utleie WHERE baatinn = '0' ORDER BY id desc";

$result = $conn-> query($sql);


if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>". 
        $row["utleid"] ."</td><td>".
        $row["inntid"] ."</td><td>".
        $row["baatnr"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["fornavn"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["etternavn"] ."</td><td>". 
        $row["tid"] ."</td><td>".
        $row["kr"] ."</td></tr>"; 
    }
echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

echo $row;

$conn-> close();

?>

</table>
```

Comment: Did you tried use JavaScript for that? I that would be your way to go

Comment: I figured out i had to use javascript. Tried something but failed drastically :P

Comment: You don't need JS for that. Using PHP to do it, you set the class as the page loads, and aren't dependent on rendering parts of the table after its loaded. I'd say using JS is more work than doing it as you load the results in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Define your CSS class to be whatever you'd like it to be if the condition is true, then check if the time of `$row['tid']` is equal or higher to the current date - if true, add that class to your `td` element.

CSS would be something like

```
.future_time {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And your PHP would be something like this,

```
<?php 
$sok = @$_POST['searchh'];
$sql = "SELECT utleid, inntid, baatnr, fornavn, etternavn, tid, kr FROM utleie WHERE baatinn = '0' ORDER BY id desc";

$result = $conn-> query($sql);


if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    $now = new DateTime();
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        $tid = new DateTime($row["tid"]);
        $tid_class = $tid >= $now ? 'future_time' : '';
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["utleid"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["inntid"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["baatnr"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["fornavn"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["etternavn"]; ?></td>
            <td class="<?php echo $tid_class; ?>"><?php echo $tid ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["kr"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn-> close();
```

Comment: Hmm, didnt seem to work. Could it be because DateTime() gets more values than just Hours and minutes. Or am i wrong?

Comment: The `DateTIme` class is pretty clever. What is the actual value of `$row['tid']`, what format is it in?

Comment: And when you say "didn't seem to work", you'll need to be a bit more specific. What happens, does any errors appear (if not, are you checking for and logging them?)

Comment: I had to go to work but i got a long error code. Ill check when i come home.

Comment: As you can see from [this sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1560159d1dbb91428f3b8990b8c52c56aecfa65c), the DateTime is quite clever, and would figure out that you're giving it times only (and it'll default to the date of January 1st, 1970, but that's irrelevant). Show your error, without it its impossible to help.. :-)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (125) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character in /var/www/html/testing.php:49 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/testing.php(49): DateTime->__construct('125') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/testing.php on line 49

Comment: What is the exact value of your tid? `var_dump($row['tid`])`